# Using POM with java

Tags: selenium, java

@Thanks the_coder
As he explained ;
 I have add some lines to my PageObject class.
And then use them on the same class.
Then call the login method from my test by creating an object reference.

But i was getting the following error.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Which was resolved by adding the following constructor to the Page object class

```
public POMLogin()
{
  PageFactory.initElements(jUnitLogintest.driver, this);
}
```

[image]

Comment: I saw this at the consol:INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
JavaScript error: http://www.XXXX.com/clientscript/vbulletin_md5.js?v=387, line 1: SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'
JavaScript warning: http://www.XXXX.com/forum/combank/index.html, line 42: mutating the [[Prototype]] of an object will cause your code to run very slowly; instead create the object with the correct initial [[Prototype]] value using Object.create
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx1024M

Comment: Oooh god. I miss this part.public POMLogin()
     {
         PageFactory.initElements(jUnitLogintest.driver, this);
     }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create methods (actions to be done on the elements) in your page object like the following:

**Page Object**

```
class POMLogin
{
 // Web Elements

 public void login()
 {
   UsernameTxtBox.sendKeys("x");
   PasswordTxtBox.sendKeys("y");
   ButtonLgn.click();
 }
}
```

And use the page objects in your test class

**Test Class:**

```
# Pseudo code
import packagename.POMLogin;
public void TestClass
{
    @Test
    public void LoginCheck()
    {
      POMLogin pom = new POMLogin();
      pom.login();
     // Then perform your assert here
    }
}
```

The above code is just a pseudo code.

Comment: Thanks your answer makes me feel soo easy to implement this POM in java